# Getting error "The function value at x=nan is NaN; solver cannot continue." while creating a custom distribution in scipy

Tags: scipy, scipy.stats

I was trying to learn using **SciPy** and
I want to create a custom distribution with the pdf defined as :

f(x) = k * x ^ (k-1) if 0 < x < 1 else 0

Based on the [documentation on the scipy website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/stats.html#making-a-continuous-distribution-i-e-subclassing-rv-continuous) I've defined the custom distribution as:

```py
k = 7

class custom_distro(stats.rv_continuous):
  def _pdf(self, x):
    return k*math.pow(x,k-1) if (0<=x<=1) else 0
```

Now the `custom_distro.pdf()` and `custom_distro.cdf()` functions are working fine, but using the function `.rvs()` gives the error:

**The function value at x=nan is NaN; solver cannot continue.**

I've tried to search for what the issue is but I cannot find any helpful suggestion.

I'd also request that if you have some good resources for the library please do suggest.

Comment: The example in the documentation shows creating a class with a cdf, and the pdf is automatically computed from it. Does scipy.stats support the opposite?

Comment: Yes. It does support defining _pdf only, even though the generic cdf computation is very inefficient (quad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the custom_distro.pdf() and custom_distro.cdf() functions are working fine

This is surprising, because `custom_distro` is a subclass of `rv_continuous`, but each SciPy (continuous) distributions is an *instance* of a subclasses of `rv_continuous`. For example `norm_gen` is a subclass of `rv_continuous`, and `scipy.stats.norm` is an instance of `norm_gen`. (It's weird, I know.)

Another part of the problem may have been that your distribution has finite support (your `_pdf` returned 0 when `x` was outside the interval `[0, 1]`), but it is better to define the support of the distribution using the appropriate feature of the infrastructure. The infrastructure will take care of ensuring that the `pdf` method returns 0 when the argument is outside the support, etc.

Here is code for which the `rvs` method works.

```py
from scipy import stats
import math

# note that the class is named with _gen appended
class custom_distro_gen(stats.rv_continuous):
  def _pdf(self, x, k):
    return k*math.pow(x, k-1)
    # I'd recommend using operators, e.g.
    # k * x**(k-1)
    # Then you can use NumPy arrays
    # But if `k` can be 0 or less, you'll need to make
    # sure `x` is not of integer type or you could get an
    # error (can't evaluate integer to negative integer power)

  # consider defining the `_argcheck` method if there
  # are restrictions on the parameter `k`

# `custom_distro` should be an instance of the `custom_distro_gen` class
# `a` and `b` define the support of the distribution; the value of the pdf
# is zero outside of the support. 
custom_distro = custom_distro_gen(name='custom_distro', a=0, b=1)
custom_distro.rvs(k=2.)  # 0.875097877164333

# freeze the distribution with k=2
dist = custom_distro(k=2.)
dist.rvs(size=5)  # array([0.89701868, 0.65968075, 0.29795727, 0.56256978, 0.25515445])
```

There is some additional information about adding new distributions at [Adding a New Statistics Distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/dev/contributor/adding_new.html#adding-a-new-statistics-distribution). Looking at PRs in which distributions were added will also be helpful, e.g. [gh-12694](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12694).

> I was trying to learn using SciPy...

Creating custom distributions is rather advanced. The process is [poorly documented](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/12133), and there are [many issues](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15928) with the infrastructure, so I would not recommend starting with this. Consider following one of the other [tutorials](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Thanks alot! I thought doing my assignment using SciPy will be a good way to try out the library, cause the documentation has always kept me at bay.